# PayPal PDT and no transaction token returned

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-pdt

I'm trying to get pdt data back from paypal sandbox, seems pretty straightforward but I don't get any data actually.
I'm able to call the service and get the callback but there is no data.

I'm following this example:
https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_pdt.php

and also did set my *selling tools settings* specifying:

- Auto return: on
- Payment Data Transfer: on

The main issue is the transaction token, the line below has no value

```
$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
```

Do I need some specific configuration on my server or what else I'm missing here?
Should I use IPN?

Thanks

Comment: Did you put token in your client side?

Comment: If you mean the identity token, I use it in my callback url (in my php defined as callback url) when I call https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. Referring to the example at the link above, I changed the value with my identity token at line 10.